# How to eliminate dummy indices in Package-X

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm using a package called Package-X that computes things involving summation over dummy indices (using Einstein summation conventions). In the output of the computation the dummy indices sometimes show up inn the form "\$" followed by some number e.g. "\$123". My problem is that there are sometimes two terms with the same summation however because their dummy indices are labelled differently it doesn't simplify them together.

Is there some way to process the output so that the dummy indices which are given names like \$123 \$232 etc can be chosen from a list of symbols? e.g. can I make them all 'a' or 'b' so which would simplify the answer.

In raw form the code for such a term in the output is:

DiracMatrix[LTensor[DiracG, \$152], DiracPL]]LTensor[LeviCivitaE, $152, {e1}, {e3}, {k3}]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit your question and add details on the package you are using and code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: There is a function ``X`Utilities`ClearDuplicatedTensors`` in the package; does that help?

Comment: Thank you @QuantumDot ! That fixed the issue perfectly! How did you find this function? I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: I usually find hidden functions using `*`.  I ran the command ``?X`*`*`` and found some things in `Utilities`.  You can try it too.